# Why is druid roll up not working as expected?

Tags: druid

I have the following druid ingestion spec which reads data from kafka and generates some aggregates. Right now I am only interested in the count. It has two dimensions `PURCHASE_STATUS` and `STORE_ID`. Now I want the data to be rolled up and bucketed for a minute level granularity.

```
  "type": "kafka",
  "spec": {
    "dataSchema": {
      "dataSource": "purchase",
      "timestampSpec": {
        "column": "timestamp",
        "format": "millis",
        "missingValue": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
      },
      "dimensionsSpec": {
        "dimensions": [
          {
            "type": "string",
            "name": "PURCHASE_STATUS",
            "multiValueHandling": "SORTED_ARRAY",
            "createBitmapIndex": true
          },
          {
            "type": "string",
            "name": "STORE_ID",
            "multiValueHandling": "SORTED_ARRAY",
            "createBitmapIndex": true
          }
        ],
        "dimensionExclusions": [
          "__time",
          "total_count",
          "timestamp",
        ],
        "includeAllDimensions": false
      },
      "metricsSpec": [
        {
          "type": "count",
          "name": "total_count"
        }
      ],
      "granularitySpec": {
        "type": "uniform",
        "segmentGranularity": "TEN_MINUTE",
        "queryGranularity": "MINUTE",
        "rollup": true,
        "intervals": []
      },
```

Now when I query druid using the following query

```
SELECT
__time, STORE_ID, PURCHASE_STATUS, total_count
FROM mz_purchase
WHERE __time >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '30' MINUTE ORDER BY __time DESC
```

I get the following results

```
2022-12-07T06:37:00.000Z    1   Status1 3
2022-12-07T06:37:00.000Z    1   Status2 2
2022-12-07T06:37:00.000Z    1   Status1 1
2022-12-07T06:37:00.000Z    1   Status3 23

I am confused why we are getting multiple aggregates for the same timestamp bucket and combination of dimensions.
```

Comment: Found out the issue. Rollups are not perfect for real time ingestion https://www.rilldata.com/blog/seeking-the-perfect-apache-druid-rollup

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. The explanation is that real-time ingestion cannot provide perfect rollup. Here's why:

- real-time ingestion is scalable because it can be partitioned end-to-end
- multiple ingestion tasks can be used to consume from a stream that uses stream partitioning, enabling end-to-end scalability
- this causes imperfect rollup because the stream partitions are processed by different tasks and each task builds aggregates independently,
- streaming messages that share rollup dimension values but are processed in separate tasks will end up in different rolled up rows and in separate segment files

In order to query imperfect rollup ingested data, you need to aggregate again at query time to finalize the rollup.
It is also a best practice to follow up real-time ingestions with [compaction](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/data-management/compaction.html) tasks that can further optimize the segments for query by completing the rollup and potentially applying [secondary partitioning](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/ingestion/partitioning.html#secondary-partitioning) strategy to improve query performance of historical timeframes.